# Dynamic QImage , when no initial size specified

Tags: qt, paint, qt4.8

I'm trying to use QPainter to draw items onto a QImage , but since I can't predict the exact size of this QImage , I can't use QImage::save() , it always tell me:

`QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3`

But if I specify the image height and width when declaring this QImage , it works smoothly:

`QImage output = QImage (500 , 500 , QImage::Format_ARGB32);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QImage`, `QPixmap`, etc. require data to be allocated before drawing can begin.  Using the default constructor of `QImage` does not allocate any memory, so `image.isNull() == true`.  So when you call `QPainter::begin()` (probably indirectly by creating one with the `QImage` as the paint device) it can't draw into any memory because it isn't there.

From the `QPainter::begin()` docs:

```
QPixmap image(0, 0);
painter->begin(&image); // impossible - image.isNull() == true;
```

So you have to come up with a size before drawing.  In your situation, the best thing to do would be to decide on a maximum size (or calculate one if feasible), and then once you do know the exact size - crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can draw on a `QGraphicsScene` which will expand automatically as you add items on it, then save only the painted area given by `QGraphicsScene::itemsBoundingRect()`:

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
scene.addItem(...);

QImage image(scene.itemsBoundingRect().size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);

QPainter painter(&image);
scene.render(&painter, image.rect(), scene.itemsBoundingRect());
```